# Ratio of consecutive divisors and average 

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, probabilistic-number-theory, divisors-multiples

Let $2\leq d_1 < d_2,...,d_l < n$ be all the proper nontrivial divisors of $n$. I like to understand how much these divisors deviates from each other. Here are two questions in this regard:

(1) What is the maximum of the set $\{d_i/d_{i-1}: 1\leq i \leq l\}$. Say it $M$.

Assume that you know the prime factorization of $n (= p_1^{\alpha_1}..p_r^{\alpha_r})$. Can I have a formula in terms of $p_i$'s and $\alpha_i$'s. One of the crude upper bound can be $p_r$ but this is really bad if $n$ has many distinct prime factors.

(2) Instead of maximum, the average may be more interesting and useful. So can we estimate 
the mean and variance,

$\mu = (1/l)\sum_{i=1}^{l}{d_i/d_{i-1}}$ and $\sigma^2 = (1/l)\sum_{i=1}^{l}{(d_i/d_{i-1}-\mu)^2}$

Comment: I would ask Kevin Ford at the University of Illinois. A few years he published a long paper in the Annals about divisors in an interval.

Comment: http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2008/168-2/p01

Comment: But $H(x, y, z) - H(x-\Delta, y, z)$ can be computed only if $\Delta \geq x/\log^{10}{z}$, (as in Introduction, Theorem 2, in above mentioned paper). Then recovering the integer whose divisor we have to look at is not possible by this formula. 

Comment: This may be worth studying if n has many divisors.  What significance do you see it having for n having fewer than 5 divisors?
Or 10?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.12.07

Comment: Also, assuming d_0 is 1, it is clear that M is at least p_1, where I assume the prime factors are indexed in order of increasing magnitude, and that for n with many factors, log of the mean will
be close to if not equal to log of n divided by number of divisors
of n.  There may be some bizarre exceptions like a twice a large ppprime taken to a large power, but they should be easy to characterize.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Gut Feeling" Paseman, 2012.12.07

Comment: But I feel it significantly deviates from $\log n$ if there are many distinct prime factor that are close to each other. 

Comment: OK.  See what you can do to substantiate your feeling.  Gerhard "Race You To Some Proof" Paseman, 2012.12.07

Comment: There may be something of use in the book, Hall and Tenenbaum, Divisors. A review is at http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?verb=Display&version=1.0&service=UI&handle=euclid.bams/1183555470&page=record --- also, Helmut Maier has written on what may be related problems. 

Comment: It is an old conjecture from Erdös (that is, afaik, still open) that almost all integers $n$ have two divisors $d_1$ and $d_2$ with $d_1 < d_2 < 2d_1$. 

Comment: No, I am not correct. This conjecture has been proven by Maier and Tenenbaum in in their 1984 paper 'on the set of divisors of an integer', which was published in Invent. Math.

Comment: By Erdos conjecture, the minimum is less than 2. It will be interesting if similar results holds for maximum, means with some density 1 criterion. May be Tenenbaum's formulation(That appears in Andreas answer) is useful for it. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tenenbaum [Sur un probleme de crible et ses applications (1986)] showed that 
$$ F(n)/n=\max_{1\le i < \tau(n)} \frac{d_{i+1}(n)}{d_i(n)},$$
where $1=d_1(n)< \ldots < d_{\tau(n)}(n)=n$ is the increasing sequence of divisors, and 
$F$ is given by $F(1)=1$ and $F(n)=\max \{ d P^{-}(d) : d|n,\, d>1 \}$ for $n\ge 2$, where $P^{-}(n)$ is the smallest prime divisor of $n$. 
For $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$, with $p_1<\ldots < p_k$, this leads to the formula
$$ \max_{1\le i < \tau(n)} \frac{d_{i+1}(n)}{d_i(n)}
= \max_{1 \le j \le k} \{ p_j p_j^{\alpha_j}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k} \}/n$$

Let $D(x,t)=|\{n\le x: F(n)/n \le t\}|$. Saias [Entiers a diviseurs denses 1 (1997)] showed that $D(x,t) \asymp x\log t /\log x$ for $x\ge t \ge 2$. I showed [Integers with dense divisors, 2 (2004)] that $D(x,t)=x\, d(w) \{1+O(1/\log t) \}$, for $x\ge 3$, $x\ge t \ge \exp\{(\log(\log(x)))^{5/3+\varepsilon}\}$, where $w=\log x / \log t$ and $d(w)$ is a continuous function that can be expressed in terms of Dickman's function and which satisfies $d(w) \asymp 1/w$.

2015 Update: In [arXiv:1405.2585], I found that $D(x,t)=x\, d(w) \{1+O(1/\log t) \}$, for $x\ge t \ge 2$.

Comment: In definition of $F(n)$ is $d\leq n$ ?  

Comment: Yes, $d|n$ implies $d\le n$ in the definition of $F$.

Comment: small typo $\max_{1\le i < \tau(n)} \frac{d_{i+1}(n)}{d_i(n)}
= \max_{\substack{0 < \beta_j \le \alpha_j \\ 0 \le \beta_{j+l} \le \alpha_{j+l}\\ 1 \le l}} \{ p_j p_j^{\beta_j}\cdots p_k^{\beta_k} \}/n$

Comment: I don't think there is a typo. Because you are looking for a maximum, you can take $\beta_i = \alpha_i$. 

Comment: yes, what I was thinking is reductive.

Comment: If you have a value for $F(n)/n$ for density 1 , will you like to add it to the answer. Yet I have not found a way to calculate the mean. 

Comment: We have $D(x,t) \asymp x \log t / \log x$ for $x \ge t \ge 2$, a result due to Saias. So for fixed $t$, the integers with $F(n)/n \le t$ have zero density.